# already existing html templates with GWT

Tags: html, templates, jakarta-ee, gwt, uibinder

I want to know how to use already existing html templates with gwt
because for my project I have html design that i'm obliged to use
thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Copy your HTML into a UiBinder template, putting it inside an HTMLPanel. Then you can selectively replace some HTML elements with GWT widgets where additional functionality is required, and reference these widgets in your corresponding view. Alternatively, you can reference elements, if you don't need widget functionality.

This option is the only option if you have multiple HTML templates and you want to turn them into a single-page GWT app.

2. Use your HTML as a host page, adding ids to the elements you want to make interactive. Then you can get these elements from your GWT code and manipulate them as necessary.

Comment: and if my templates have multiple Html pages can i use these options ?

Comment: You have to turn each "page" into a separate view within your GWT app. Each view can use a UiBinder template.

Comment: ok and I can use both option you mentionned ?
and what about the UIDOM